# How do I get back to chapters after doing side missions in Thief?

Tags: thief

I decided to talk to a random guy in a tavern just before starting Chapter 5, and he gave me a mission to steal a skull. After completing this, I got put back into the city with no waypoint marker (which I had before starting the side mission). Any ideas where I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are waypoint markers for all your active missions on the map, that you can access in the ingame menu (journal). To activate a mission marker to be displayed at all time in game, go to "view map", search for the starting point, move the cursor over the mission and choose "track objective".

Alternatively, you can go to the "objectives" tab in the journal and choose the option to track the objective from there.

There should be a marker to the starting point of Chapter 5 somewhere on the map. If you can't find it, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhkjknnBYRI) is a video with the starting points of all missions.

Comment: Thanks! Went into menu->objectives as suggested and tagged the marker for Chapter 5

Comment: @AlexBlundell I would upvote the answer in addition to accepting it (which you have already done).